# Counting strings of text in batch

Tags: string, text, batch-file, count

I have been looking round and I'm able to find ways of counting lines in a txt file but is there a way i can count for a specific string of text and then place that value in a log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FIND command with the /C option counts and prints the number of matching lines. Anything that is printed to the screen can be redirected to a log file.

```
find /c "your string" yourFile >yourLog
```

The above includes the name of the file in the output. If you want only the count, then use redirection or a pipe

```
find /c "your string" <yourFile >yourLog

or

type yourFile | find /c "your string" >yourLog
```

All of the above count the number of *lines* that contain the string. If the string can appear multiple times in the same line and you want to count the total number of times the *string* appears in the file, then the solution will be much more complex.